# H2 Database: Error while trying to use RunScript

Tags: h2

Iam trying to use Run script to create h2 db from the sql, sql file is created by Recovery tool using `java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Recover`

Trying to create db from sql using below

```
java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript -url jdbc:h2:./mdata -user sa -script mdata.h2.sql
```

---

```
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.NullPointerException"; SQL statement: INSERT INTO O_22 VALUES(120, '102567', 'content', '{"contentFormat":"some","binary":false}', READ_CLOB_DB(15507, 6300)) [50000-186]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:295)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTable.addRow(MVTable.java:641)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:156)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:114)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:78)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:254)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:184)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:158)
    at org.h2.tools.RunScript.process(RunScript.java:260)
    at org.h2.tools.RunScript.process(RunScript.java:190)
    at org.h2.tools.RunScript.process(RunScript.java:328)
    at org.h2.tools.RunScript.runTool(RunScript.java:141)
    at org.h2.tools.RunScript.main(RunScript.java:68)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.h2.store.LobStorageMap.setTable(LobStorageMap.java:281)
    at org.h2.value.ValueLobDb.link(ValueLobDb.java:245)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVPrimaryIndex.add(MVPrimaryIndex.java:120)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTable.addRow(MVTable.java:637)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Could you retry with a newer version? You are using version 1.4.186, the current version is 1.4.196

Comment: Hi Thomas, the db is created using 1.4.186 and i tried Recover and Runscript using 1.4.196 and got similar error. Should the db also be created using 1.4.196 for this to work?

Comment: @Thomas Can you help me with above?